# Propel / Symfony 1.4: combine securely custom sql subquery with criteria

Tags: mysql, symfony-1.4, criteria, propel, mysql-real-escape-string

I want to insert a custom sql subquery into a common Propel criteria. The subquery contains user inputs, so these have to be escaped. How can I realize this?

I have something like this (simplyfied):

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(myTablePeer::CUSTOMER_ID, 123);
$c->add... //several other criterions, joins etc.
$subQuery = "(SELECT SUM(id) FROM my_other_table WHERE customer_id = 123) > '[USERINPUT]'";
$c->add("", $subQuery, Criteria::CUSTOM);
```

So, of course, this subquery is vulnerable to SQL injects. How can I secure this query in the best way? I cannot use mysqli_real_escape_string(), can I? So just addslashes() and that's it?

Comment: i don't know the answer but please don't just use addslashes() that won't do the trick. (http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: No you cannot use `mysqli_real_escape_string` - Propel uses PDO im pretty sure... What version of Propel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Propel 1.4.2

Comment: I know addslashes is not 100% reliable, but anyway better than nothing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Halleluja, I think I found the solution:

```
Propel::getConnection()->quote($userInput)
```

This does the magic. Quoting and escaping in one step!
So the subQuery would be:

```
$subQuery = "(SELECT SUM(id) FROM my_other_table WHERE customer_id = 123) > ".Propel::getConnection()->quote($userInput);
```

Can someone verifiy, that this is the best way to secure the input?